# Add lines under condition within ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I kindly ask you help me on this issue.

Please look Data below:

Name  StartDate  EndDate

John  17.07.2016 17.07.2017

John  17.07.2017  17.07.2018

Maria 01.08.2017  01.08.2018

Chris 05.01.2018  05.01.2019

Workers and their working years. I need to add new  line for worker when his/her working year finished. For example when the **date** > 17.07.2018 I need to add new line for John. (**date = today formula**)

It look like simple but this is a part of my vacation module.

I started to write code like this.

```
Sub AddWorkingYearLine()

Dim WorVac As Worksheet:                Set WorVac = Worksheets("WorkerVacation")
Dim i As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long
Dim MyTable As Variant

LRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row: LCol = Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Column

MyTable = Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(LRow, LCol))

For i = 1 To UBound(MyTtable, 1)

If Branches.Range("C" & i) > Range("G1") Then  'Range("G1") = today formula

End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of your request. If column "C" of the current row occurs before today then it will insert a row, copy the current row into that new row, and then increment the year on those dates.

```
Sub AddWorkingYearLine()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row To 4 Step -1
        'make sure it's not an "old entry"
        If Cells(i, "A").Value2 <> Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2 Then
            'if today occurs after "end date" then
            If Date > CDate(Cells(i, "C").value) And Len(Cells(i, "C").Value2) > 0 Then
                'insert row
                Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

                'copy row down
                Rows(i + 1).value = Rows(i).value

                'update dates
                Cells(i + 1, "B").value = Cells(i, "C").value
                Cells(i + 1, "C").value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CDate(Cells(i, "C").value))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your good solution. The code work properly for standard range of data. but I use table for my data. How can I adjust your code for Table style??

Comment: Sorry for additional question. Everything work properly. Thanks a lot for your support.